# Unicode character for "X" cancel / close?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I want to create a close button using CSS only.

I'm sure I'm not the first to do this, so does anyone know which font has an 'x' the same width as height, so that it can be used cross-browser to look like a close button?

Answer (score 707, accepted):

✖ works really well. The HTML code is `&#10006;`.

An alternative is `&#x2715;`: ✕

Comment: Note that you have to use a font that supports this character. I think DejaVu looks nice for that. I think `Lucida Sans Unicode` and `Arial Unicode MS` also support such unicode symbols. If you don't use a font that supports these characters on some browsers (especially old IE) all you will get are rectangles indicating unsupported symbols. I use a stripped down version of DejaVu for such symbols.

Comment: See the comment above by panzi.

Comment: That is an excellent character for the purpose. Do you know what that character is actually "supposed" to be?

Comment: It is called 'Heavy Multiplication X' I believe - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2716/index.htm

Comment: 2 years later, this comment just made my project kick that extra amount of ass I was looking for!

Comment: Now if only we could change the color in FireFox 32.0, its always red even when setting the color css

Comment: Four years later, doing Java Swing development and this works great on a JButton! Usage: JButton button = new JButton("<html>&#10006;<html/>");

Comment: I found something not so amazing about this symbol. You can't control its color. It's always black. I've tried a class with color:#fff, a style with color:#fff, and even tried to apply a span wrapper. Nada. Always black.

Comment: @Tarkus its' color is the CSS `color` value of the element that surrounds it (or any parent)

Comment: Another (more attractive IMO) option is &#x2715;

Comment: this is the best and simplest answer! No css no bootstrap just a one liner! BRAVO!

Comment: Unfortunatly you can't colorized &#10006; with css (e.g. color: white), but with &times; you can do it.

Comment: Works also for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) in .NET

Answer (score 101):

**HTML**

✕  `&#x2715;`  ✓   `&#x2713;`
✖  `&#x2716;`  ✔  `&#x2714;`

✗ `&#x2717;`
✘ `&#x2718;`

×  `&#x00d7;`  `&times;`

**CSS**

Inside a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element use the escaped `\` Unicode HEX value like:

```css
[class^="ico-"], [class*=" ico-"] {
  font: normal 1em/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ico-times::before { content: "\2716"; }
.ico-check::before { content: "\2714"; }
```

```html
<i class="ico-times" role="img" aria-label="Cancel"></i>
<i class="ico-check" role="img" aria-label="Accept"></i>
```

#### Use cases:

| Language | Syntax | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HTML | &#x2715; | `<button class="close" type="button">&#x2715; Close</button>` |
| CSS | \2715 | `.close::before { content: '\2715'; }` |
| JavaScript | \u2715 | `document.querySelector(".close").prepend("\u2715")` |

https://home.unicode.org/

Comment: Thanks for the CSS escaping tip

Answer (score 93):

What about using the ×-mark (the multiplication symbol), `&times;` in HTML, for that?

"x" (letter) should not be used to represent anything else other than the letter X.

Comment: Going with your logic - also x-times should represent only x times. I would say either use an image or the word close.

Comment: Yup, this is also true, I know.

Comment: "x" (letter) should not be used to represent anything else that the X letter. -  who says that? if thats just you whats the logic behind that. thanks

Comment: You can also use multiplication character ' × '. Taken from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912989/css-font-twitter-like-close-button-what-did-i-missing).

Comment: Best answer IMHO. I think all browsers will support this and if Bootstrap is using it... they usually follow best practices.

Comment: Love this! Easier to remember than &#10006;

Comment: Yes, the letter *x* [should _definitely_ not be used to represent multiplication or a close button](https://wesbos.com/times-html-entity-close-button/), _because it's a different character_.  It's often done by people who are too lazy, in a hurry, or who don't care about quality.  Just like people sometimes use a lower-case _b_ to represent a musical flat symbol, but that doesn't make it a good idea to follow their example.

Answer (score 77):

Fonts with Square-Shaped "X"

- **Monospace Fonts**: Fonts like Courier New or Monaco are designed with characters that each occupy the same amount of horizontal space, making the "X" square-shaped.
- **Web Safe Fonts**: Fonts like Arial and Verdana are generally well-proportioned and are available on most systems, making them a safe choice for web use.
- **Icon Fonts**: Fonts like FontAwesome offer a dedicated close icon that is designed to be square-shaped.

This should work in all browsers as far back as IE6.  If you don't care about IE6 thru 8 just remove the css hacks and conditional comment.

```css
/* IE 6 and 7 code */
.close {
  *position: relative; /* IE7 and below */
  _position: relative; /* IE6 */
}
.close span {
  *position: absolute; /* IE7 and below */
  _position: absolute; /* IE6 */
  *top: 15px;
  _top: 15px;
  *right: 15px;
  _right: 15px;
  *font-size: 1.5em;
  _font-size: 1.5em;
  *color: #000;
  _color: #000;
}
.close:hover span {
  *color: #888;
  _color: #888;
}
/* End - IE 6 and 7 code */

.close:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #000;
  font-size:1.5em;
  content: '×'
}
.close:hover:before {
  color: #888
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="close">
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><span>×</span><![endif]-->
</a>
```

---

- Mathematical Symbols

  - Multiplication Sign

    - **Symbol**: ×
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#215;` or `&times;`
    - **Unicode**: U+00D7
    - **Description**: Used to denote multiplication in mathematical equations.
    - **Use Case**: `5 × 3 = 15`
  - Multiplication Sign with Strong Font Weight

    - **Symbol**: × (same character but with strong font weight)
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#215;` or `&times;` (styled with CSS for strong font weight)
    - **Unicode**: U+00D7
    - **Description**: A bolder version of the multiplication sign, often used for emphasis.
    - **Use Case**: Styling headers or labels where multiplication is involved.
  - Gibbs Product

    - **Symbol**: ⨯
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10799;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2A2F
    - **Description**: Used in vector calculus and Gibbs notation.
    - **Use Case**: `A ⨯ B` to denote the vector cross product of A and B.
  - Heavy Multiplication Sign

    - **Symbol**: ✖
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10006;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2716
    - **Description**: A thicker, more emphasized version of the multiplication sign.
    - **Use Case**: Graphic design, UI elements, or to highlight important multiplicative factors.
  - Circled Multiplication Sign

    - **Symbol**: ⊗
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#8855;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2297
    - **Description**: Used in various mathematical contexts, including tensor products.
    - **Use Case**: `A ⊗ B` to denote the tensor product of A and B.
  - Circled Plus

    - **Symbol**: ⊕
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#8853;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2295
    - **Description**: Used in mathematics, computer science, and engineering.
    - **Use Case**: Exclusive OR (XOR) operations, direct sum in algebra.
- Text and Linguistics

  - Latin Capital Letter X

    - **Symbol**: X
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#88;`
    - **Unicode**: U+0058
    - **Description**: The Latin capital letter X, not to be confused with the multiplication sign.
    - **Use Case**: Text, labeling, and non-mathematical contexts.
  - Latin Small Letter X

    - **Symbol**: x
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#120;`
    - **Unicode**: U+0078
    - **Description**: The Latin small letter x, often used in algebraic equations.
    - **Use Case**: `f(x) = x^2` to denote a function of x.
  - Chi (Greek Letter)

    - **Symbol**: χ
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#967;`
    - **Unicode**: U+03C7
    - **Description**: The Greek letter Chi, used in various scientific fields.
    - **Use Case**: Statistics (Chi-square test), quantum mechanics (spin–orbit interaction).
  - Mathematical Bold Capital Chi

    - **Symbol**:
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#12046;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2E9E
    - **Description**: The bold version of the Greek letter Chi, used in mathematical notation.
    - **Use Case**: Boldface variables in mathematical papers, especially in contexts involving vectors or matrices.
  - Cross Accent

    - **Symbol**: ˟
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#7387;`
    - **Unicode**: U+1D1F
    - **Description**: A small x-shaped diacritic.
    - **Use Case**: Linguistic notation, specialized alphabets.
- User Interface and Graphic Design

  - Emoji X

    - **Symbol**: ❌
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10060;`
    - **Unicode**: U+274C
    - **Description**: Generally used to indicate 'no', 'wrong', or 'cancel'.
    - **Use Case**: User interfaces to indicate a failed task or to cancel operations.
  - Cross Mark Button

    - **Symbol**:
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#128308;`
    - **Unicode**: U+1F7E4
    - **Description**: A red square with a white cross, often used to indicate 'no' or 'stop'.
    - **Use Case**: User interfaces, warning messages.
  - Cross Mark

    - **Symbol**: ❎
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10062;`
    - **Unicode**: U+274E
    - **Description**: Used to indicate 'no', 'wrong', or 'cancel'.
    - **Use Case**: User interfaces, forms.
  - Crosshair

    - **Symbol**: ⌖
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#8974;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2316
    - **Description**: Represents a target or focus point.
    - **Use Case**: Graphic design, shooting games, or as a cursor in some software.
  - Box Drawing Light Diagonal Cross

    - **Symbol**: ╳
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#9583;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2573
    - **Description**: Used in box drawing characters for creating frames and boxes.
    - **Use Case**: Text-based user interfaces, ASCII art.
- Heraldry and Religious Symbols

  - St. Andrew's Cross

    - **Symbol**: ☓
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#9763;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2613
    - **Description**: A saltire or diagonal cross, often used in heraldry.
    - **Use Case**: Flags, emblems, and as a warning sign for harmful substances.
  - Maltese Cross

    - **Symbol**: ✠
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10016;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2720
    - **Description**: A symbol often associated with the Knights of Malta.
    - **Use Case**: Heraldry, religious contexts, or to denote a special achievement in some video games.
  - Saltire (St. Patrick's Cross)

    - **Symbol**: ⚔
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#9876;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2694
    - **Description**: A symbol often used to represent St. Patrick's Cross or crossed swords.
    - **Use Case**: Heraldry, military insignias, or to denote battle/fight in games.
  - Cross of Jerusalem

    - **Symbol**: ✚
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10010;`
    - **Unicode**: U+271A
    - **Description**: A cross with four arms of equal length.
    - **Use Case**: Religious contexts, historical references.
  - Celtic Cross

    - **Symbol**: ✜
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#10012;`
    - **Unicode**: U+271C
    - **Description**: A cross with a circle around the intersection.
    - **Use Case**: Religious and cultural symbols, tattoos.
- Miscellaneous Symbols

  - Crossed Swords

    - **Symbol**: ⚔️
    - **HTML Entity**: `&#9876;&#65039;`
    - **Unicode**: U+2694 U+FE0F
    - **Description**: Two crossed swords, often used to represent battle or conflict.
    - **Use Case**: Social media, games, or to denote conflict in text.

##### Various X-shaped Unicode characters which can be represented using UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 26):

✕ is another great one that's not too thick. The HTML code is `&#10005;`, or `2715` in hex.

Answer (score 21):

As @Haza pointed out the times symbol can be used.  [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) maps this to a [close icon](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#misc) for dismissing content like modals and alerts.

```
<button class="close">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Informative by pointing that Bootstrap uses this but it is a duplicated answer, it is the same as @Haza 's.

Answer (score 15):

## ― 2021 Update

As of Unicode 7.0 (June 2014): [U+1F5D9 "Cancellation X"](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=1F5D9)

Comment: I can't visually see that as a "cancel" icon.

Comment: @SơnTrần-Nguyễn OK, but it is both what OP asks for and very similar to all the other answers here.

Comment: Semantically, this is the only correct answer here.

Answer (score 13):

```
&#x274C;
```

looks like:

❌

its good for me :)

Answer (score 8):

This is probably pedantry, but so far no one has really given a solution "to create a close button using CSS only." only. Here you go:

```
#close:before {
  content: "✖";
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color:#eee;
  padding:0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaWqYg

Answer (score 7):

I prefer Font Awesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

The icon you would be looking for is `fa-times`. It's as simple as this to use:

```
<button><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/B5VE7/)

Comment: This is not a CSS solution.

Comment: @mevius Not sure what you are trying to say? Font Awesome doesn't require javascript and they **are** fonts. The OP asks "which font...".

Comment: @mevius Font Awesome is totally CSS - it's just an excellent wrapper for unicode: 
.fa-window-close::before {content: "\f410";}

Answer (score 6):

there's another one not mentioned here - nice thin - if you need that kind of look for your project: ╳

```
&#x2573; or decimal: &#9587;
```

Answer (score 5):

`&times;` and `font-family: Garamond, "Apple Garamond";` make it good enough. Garamond font is thin and web safe

[image: proper close X]

Comment: The only **true** web safe fonts are the generic families: serif, sans-serif & monospace. It is extremely unlikely that the average visitor to your site will have either of the fonts mentioned above available on their system. Garamond doesn't seem to be included by default in *any* OS, though you could include this one with [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). Apple Garamond however is a proprietary font historically used by Apple Inc. in their marketing material and not available for general use let alone in a commercial project.

Answer (score 4):

`&times;` is better than `&#10006;` as `&#10006;` behaves strangely in Edge and Internet explorer (tested in IE11). It doesn't get the right color and is replaced by an "emoji"

Comment: this should have more votes. I was running into an issue with css and the emoji. By using `&times;` I am able to now edit the css

Answer (score 3):

Forget about a font and use a background image!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
    <head>
        <title>Select :after pseudo class/element</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .close {
                background:url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png) NO-REPEAT -96px -128px;
                text-indent:-10000px;
                width:20px;
                height:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" class="close" value="Close" />
        <button class="close">Close</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will be more accessible for users visiting the page with a screen reader.

Comment: Why would an image be "more accessible"?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's not so much that the background image is more accessible, it's that using the word "close" (or the words "close dialog") would be clearer to a screen reader user than some random X or x-like character. The button would be labelled per what it does and not how it looks. Maybe there are better ways though - there might be a dedicated ARIA role for close buttons.

Comment: I see your point now.  But, `aria-label="Close"` is a good way to go (as shown here in this [W3 example](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA14.html) or this [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute)) and then you can use any visual indicator you want without compromising the accessibility.

Comment: Yup `aria-label` could probably work great here - but ARIA only became a completed recommendation in 2014 and I wrote this answer in 2011! Equally, the ARIA Authoring Practices also includes mis-use of `aria-label=` as an example of [ARIA which can cover up or override semantics or content](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#no_aria_better_bad_aria) in a way which is damaging to accessibility. WAI-ARIA can be easy to get wrong, and hard to test - unless a team has some dedicated a11y testing for ARIA, I discourage its use because it can do as much harm as good.

Comment: I was responding to a comment from this year, so the context of that is now, not 2011 and you can certainly update your answer to be a more current recommendation if you want.

Comment: There are plenty of other answers that reflect that approach, I don't think it's best for stackoverflow for all the answers to just converge on the same solution. The answer, the number of votes it has, and its resulting position relative to the top answer seem appropriate to me. However if you feel it should be updated you are just as free to edit it as I am.

Answer (score 3):

This works nicely for me:

```
<style>
a.closeX {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px; top: 0px; width:20px;
    background-color: #FFF; color: black;
    margin-top:-15px; margin-right:-15px; border-radius: 20px;
    padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 1px;
    cursor:pointer; z-index: -1;
    font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<div id="content">
    <a class="closeX" id="closeX" onclick='$("#content").hide();'>&#10006;</a>
    Click "X" to close this box
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is for people who want to make their `X` small/big and red!**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-2"> <span><div class="red-x">&#10006;</div></span>
    <p>close</p>
</div>

<div class="red-x big-x">&#10006;</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red-x {
color: red;
}

.big-x {
font-size: 70px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use text that is only accessible to screen readers by placing it in a span which you hide in an accessible way. Place the x in the CSS which can't be read by screen readers, thus won't confuse, but is visible on the page, and also accessible by keyboard users.

```
<style>
.hidden {opacity:0; position:absolute; width:0;}
.close {padding:4px 8px; border:1px solid #000; background-color:#fff; cursor:pointer;}
.close:before {content:'\00d7'; color:red; font-size:2em;}
</style>

<button class="close"><span class="hidden">close</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using modern browsers you can rotate a + sign:

```
.popupClose:before {
    content:'+';
}
.popupClose {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    right:10px;
    top:0px;
    padding:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:2px;
    color:grey;
    font-size:32pt;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

then simply place the following html where you need:

```
 <span class='popupClose'></span>
```

Comment: Or you could use <i class='material-icons'>close</i> (with a <head> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, someone is searching for the right and wrong marks:

```java
char rightMark = '\u2713';
char wrongMark = '\u2717';
```

Will print:

```
✓ Right Mark
✗ Wrong Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSS: just use the `content: "\d7";` which is the `&times;` html entity, so it's widely supported on mobile devices as well.

```css
.close:before {
  content: "\d7";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<span class="close"></span>
```

For those who are looking for the most supported hamburger "icon" (3 lines):

`content: "\2261";` which is the `&equiv;` html entity.