# css font twitter like close button, what did I missing?

Tags: css, twitter, fonts

twitter has it's close button which is a single character 'x'.

and i need to something like that, but after i inspect the `<span>x</span>`, i create the css rules as the firebug told me :

```
.close-button {
    font-family: Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #888;
}
```

however, they just never looks the same, what did i missing??

twitter:

[image: this is the twitter close button.]

mine:

[image: this is my close button.c]

for more information:  http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/gb23A/

Comment: Check now http://jsfiddle.net/gb23A/2/. It's not x. Just like @ArgsKwargs said.

Comment: @Beniamin yes, now i understand it, thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an alphabetical "x" look closely at the character × x X.. it's ascii

× (Multiplication Symbol)       ALT+0215

Comment: btw, i recently found that, you can simply write & times; (w/o space between `&` and `t`) to creat it :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a normal X, but a Unicode character.

Try `&#10006;`

The sign is also called 'Heavy Multiplication X' and looks like this: ✖

this question might also help you: [Unicode character for "X" cancel / close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353461/unicode-character-for-x-cancel-close#9201092)

Comment: wow, i didn't expect a new answer for my question 10 years ago :D