# Span positioning on different browsers

Tags: html, css

I have next html element:

```
<span class="ember-power-select-multiple-option">
      <span aria-label="remove element" class="ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn">×</span>
      самбука 
</span>
```

With these styles:

```
.ember-power-select-multiple-option {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: CenturyGothic;
    height: 21px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff!important;
    line-height: 19px;
    background-color: #FFB000;
    padding: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1!important;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve next: span with text and another span in it with "X" symbol. All it must be vertical aligned to middle. Now I have this[image] at MacOS X Chrome (and it looks OK to me) and [image] at Windows7 Chrome. How can I make they looks the same? And I sure exists a better way to centering span than I used.

UPDATE:

In addition, I cannot change html because it is a part of an addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in unexpected way.
First of all, I have update addon to newest version, and structure was changed.

```
<li class="ember-power-select-multiple-option">
     <span role="button" aria-label="remove element" class="ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn">×</span>
     самбука 
</li>
```

Also I set:

```
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: verdana;
```

for `ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn` class and it looks great. So I assumed that `span` in another `span` was not very good structure =).

Now it looks next [image] on both OS.

Answer (score 2):

Your symbol 'x' is vertically aligned, but is docked to top of symbols line. It's such a symbol.

Try to use ×
This simbol with this style work for me

```
.ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn {
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Threre is a question about which symbol to use
[Which font for CSS "x" close button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353461/which-font-for-css-x-close-button)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like your × that I used already. But I will try symbols from link.

Comment: I just realized that I cannot change this symbol cause it part of an addon. So I can just change css not html.

Answer (score 2):

You had repeated properties such as `padding` which will override the first one in the same class. Plus  using both`inline-block` and `float:left` will not do the effect desired on `float` so just use `inline-block`.

I've a made a few tweaks to your code:

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ember-power-select-multiple-option {
  margin:2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: CenturyGothic;
  height: 21px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 17px;
  background-color: #FFB000;
  padding: 0 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="ember-power-select-multiple-option">
      <span aria-label="remove element" class="ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn">×</span>
самбука
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just replaced the vertical-align: text-bottom; to vertical-align: middle; And I have check this in Windows7 Chrome,IE & FF and looks aligned to me. please check in MAC also.

```css
.ember-power-select-multiple-option {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: CenturyGothic;
    height: 21px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff!important;
    line-height: 19px;
    background-color: #FFB000;
    padding: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1!important;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="ember-power-select-multiple-option">
      <span aria-label="remove element" class="ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn">×</span>
      самбука 
</span>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thx. At Mac it goes lower for some reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that make use of `display: inline-flex;`

How does that look in Mac?

```css
.ember-power-select-multiple-option {
  padding: 0px 4px 1px;
  margin: 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFB000;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 21px;
}
.ember-power-select-multiple-option .text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: CenturyGothic;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff!important;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1!important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-right: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span class="ember-power-select-multiple-option">
      <span aria-label="remove element" class="ember-power-select-multiple-remove-btn">x</span>
      <span class="text">самбука</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Nope, symbol changed, but still lower. Anyway, as I mentioned in comments, I cannot change html cause it is a part of an addon.