# Unicode character to represent "fullscreen"?

Tags: unicode, icons

I'm sort of surprised that this doesn't exist given [the sheer number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#Arrows_in_Unicode) of arrow-like symbols in Unicode. Have I missed something? Or is there a character that looks similar to a fullscreen icon?

Comment: Don't search for "fullscreen", you want "maximize".  U+1F5D6.  FontAwesome is pretty popular: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=maximize.

Comment: The symbol "maximize" [U+1F5D6](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+1F5D6) is available even in most ordinary fonts, it's not specific to fontawesome.

Comment: U+1F5D6:  <-- it's probably better than ⇱︎, but (as least as I view it from the chrome browser) it doesn't really look like a "fullscreen" button (think of the icons used on video players). Although, having said that, youtube's icon doesn't really have arrows: https://i.imgur.com/nNc7PtV.png

Answer (score 32):

There is also U+26F6 "SQUARE FOUR CORNERS" ⛶ that looks somewhat similar to this image

[image: maximize button youtube]

that you've linked. No idea what the symbol was originally supposed to stand for, though... I'm also not sure that it actually does look like four corners in all fonts, maybe it's just the font of my particular browser.

Comment: To be used in **HTML**: `&#x26F6;`

Comment: To be used in **CSS**: `SELECTOR::after {
  content: '\26F6';
  padding: 10px;
}`

Comment: Unfortunately this unicode symbol is NOT yet supported in Apple MacOS/iOS (but it is already supported in Windows, Android, Linux, etc.)

Answer (score 22):

If you search for [expand](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=expand) from the link Hans Passant commented above you'll get the below

[image: "expand" search result]

**⛶** like what Youtube uses does appear among the result

Another suggestion:

- U+21F1 ⇱ North West Arrow to Corner
- U+21F2 ⇲ South East Arrow to Corner

The North East and South West versions don't exist but you can rotate or mirror the available ones to create the remaining two corners. But two corners are already enough to represent a fullscreen action, you don't need to fill all four corners

Other alternatives

- [U+2725 ✥ FOUR CLUB-SPOKED ASTERISK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2725/index.htm)
- [U+21F9 ⇹ LEFT RIGHT ARROW WITH VERTICAL STROKE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21f9/index.htm)
- [U+21FC ⇼ LEFT RIGHT ARROW WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21fc/index.htm)
- [U+2921 ⤡ NORTH WEST AND SOUTH EAST ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2921/index.htm)
- [U+1F542  CROSS POMMEE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f542/index.htm) (needs some modification or a special font to make the heads more arrow-like)
- ↔↕ (use alone or drawn onto each other to get a cross with arrows)
- ⤡⤢
- ⇳
- ⤄
- 
- 
- 
- 

Some examples with arrows

[image: player fullscreen symbol 1]
[image: player fullscreen symbol 2]

Here is another variation used by the player in [vtvgiaitri.vn](https://www.vtvgiaitri.vn)

[image: vtvgiaitri.vn player fullscreen and exit fullscreen symbols]

I guess they can be made from ◣ U+25E3 Black Lower Left Triangle and ◥ U+25E5 Black Upper Right Triangle or some of the triangles like below

- ◸ U+25F8 Upper Left Triangle
- ◹ U+25F9 Upper Right Triangle
- ◺ U+25FA Lower Left Triangle
- ◿ U+25FF Lower Right Triangle
- U+1D14A Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Left White
- U+1D14B Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Left Black
- U+1D14C Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Right White
- U+1D14D Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Right Black
- U+1D14E Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Down White
- U+1D14F Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Down Black
- U+1D150 Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Up Right White
- U+1D151 Musical Symbol Triangle Notehead Up Right Black

There are also ⤧⤨⤩⤪⤭⤮⤯⤰, unfortunately they don't have the double-head arrow version, but a simple solution like `⤪⤭` might work

You can draw on [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) to find more relevant solutions or look for more arrows on

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#Arrows_in_Unicode
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Arrows-A
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Arrows-B
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Arrows-C

Comment: For more options, there's also ◰ "White Square With Upper Left Quadrant" and the other similar ones ◱◲◳ .

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, as of this writing, YouTube is using an SVG for its "SQUARE FOUR CORNERS" icon; here's the code:

```html
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" width="100%">
<path d="m 10,16 2,0 0,-4 4,0 0,-2 L 10,10 l 0,6 0,0 z"></path>
<path d="m 20,10 0,2 4,0 0,4 2,0 L 26,10 l -6,0 0,0 z"></path>
<path d="m 24,24 -4,0 0,2 L 26,26 l 0,-6 -2,0 0,4 0,0 z"></path>
<path d="M 12,20 10,20 10,26 l 6,0 0,-2 -4,0 0,-4 0,0 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using ⇱︎, which isn't great, but sort of gets the idea across. I've also played around with "merging" characters like this:

```html
<div style="position:relative; display:inline-block;">
  <div>↖</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0;">↗</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0;">↘</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0;">↙</div>
</div>
```

Which produces this:

[image: inverted ❖]

But it'd be much nicer if there was a single character for that sort of shape.

Comment: it looks more like a square with 4 smaller squares inside to me instead of 4 arrows

Comment: it also looks a bit like ❖ (U+2756 BLACK DIAMOND MINUS WHITE X) with inverted colors.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the classic Windows "full screen" unicode icon:

[image]

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5d6/index.htm

Comment: Noice, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

```html
<sup>⇱</sup><sub>⇲</sub>
```

<sup>⇱</sup><sub>⇲</sub>

Comment: People can use these two elements two times on top of each other mirrored and get the **ULTIMATE FULLSCREEN ICON**

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of these Unicode chars:

```
⌈⌊⌊⌋
「」
┘┌└ ┐
╬
⛶
╭ ╮╯╰
```

with <sub> or <sup> + overlapping

Or arrows:

```
⇱⇲
⇳⇖⇗⇘⇙⇕⇔↔↕↖↗↘↙ (and other arrows...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the previous answer (the one mentioning "expand" icon), I feel it's convenient to use Font Awesome (https://fontawesome.com/icons/expand?s=solid&f=classic). You may also download the css file and save in the local folder.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>Font Awesome Expand icon:</p>
<i class="fa fa-expand"></i>

<p>Font Awesome Compress icon:</p>
<i class="fa fa-compress"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Google Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) includes a "fullscreen" icon that you can download as an `svg`. There's also a ◱ unicode character.

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');

path.setAttribute("d", "M200 856V663h60v133h133v60H200Zm0-367V296h193v60H260v133h-60Zm367 367v-60h133V663h60v193H567Zm133-367V356H567v-60h193v193h-60Z");
svg.setAttribute("height", "48");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 96 960 960");
svg.setAttribute("width", "48");


svg.appendChild(path);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" viewBox="0 96 960 960" width="48"><path d="M200 856V663h60v133h133v60H200Zm0-367V296h193v60H260v133h-60Zm367 367v-60h133V663h60v193H567Zm133-367V356H567v-60h193v193h-60Z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Here is your copy-pasta "", enjoy!

Source: [Maximize](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F5D6)

You might as well want to use the *Fullwidth Low Line* "＿" and one of the many [*Cross*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353461/unicode-character-for-x-cancel-close) characters available "╳".

Source: [Full-Width Underscore](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FF3F)

Long story for the curious ones: The technical term for *Full Screen* is called *Maximizing*. The writing system with many symbols for everything you need is called [Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.1.0/). You can find multiple websites with comprehensive and easy copy-pasta lists of Unicode characters, such as [compart.com](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F5D6) (It's a nice website, try it!). The *Maximize* symbol was added in June 2014 with the Unicode update v7.0.

Trivia: It works like a charm with WPF in C# .NET.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>
#fullscreen {
font-size:3em;
display: inline-block;
position: relative
}
#plus {
position: absolute;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size:2.5em;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullscreen">
<b>&#9633;</b>
<b id="plus">&#43;</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use CSS and HTML only using just 2 characters: □ and white + inside. You can zoom it. The central symmetry is guaranteed.

Comment: The file contains only 352 bytes. Just two interlaced icons , a □ and a +. The 352-byte magic of this solution lies in its elegant simplicity. Uncompromising functionality with minimal footprint. That's what sets this solution apart.