# Close button not displaying on Bootstrap dismissible alert but functions properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

I am using bootstrap dismissible alerts for a login form. All works as expected, except that the Close button doesn't display properly but works to dismiss the alert.

I am using EJS framework and an old version of Bootstrap as I am following a course.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/pulse/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHaiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I appreciate any help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS that adds the cancel/close character as an SVG icon in the Bootstrap [alert docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/alerts/#dismissing) doesn't seem to be present in the version you're using.

You could add the [Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353461/unicode-character-for-x-cancel-close) manually. Note that I also added the `btn` class, which is required for basic [Bootstrap button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/buttons/) styles.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/pulse/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" 
    aria-label="Close">✕</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHaiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```